# Edit/parse a c-function with python

Tags: python, c, parsing

I am trying to modify few existing c-functions in my project, and add a line of code at the beginning of each function using python. But I am unable to obtain the first line inside a function.
What I have tried: 
   -- using the gcc-addr2line utility to convert the absolute start address of function into the corresponding line inside c-code. However it doesn't always return the first line(in case the first operation is a conditional execution, it returns the line where first statement inside condition executes).

-- also tried using regular expression to identify the start of function.
(for ex: `void\s*_function__name_\s*\(.*\)\s*{`). Doesn't return what I need. Also I am not very experienced with this.

I do not have trouble finding the function definition, although I am not able to find the line where the first statement inside c-function exists.

Comment: Well, is it 100% of the time that the functions in a *.c file start with `void`? Your regex `void\s*_function__name_\s*\(.*\)\s*{` will always search for one and only one function not all the functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python script to print all function definitions of a C/C++ file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620851/python-script-to-print-all-function-definitions-of-a-c-c-file)

Comment: yes, the return is always void.

Comment: @GauravPathak> searching for all functions in a generic way simply cannot be done with a regular expression. On the other hand, searching for all functions with a known pattern in a known set of files might be doable. He's right exploiting the knowledge he has of his files.

Comment: @mdameenh> On the other hand, this means you must show some samples of what you're trying to find, since the solution has to be tied to your specific use case.

Comment: Looks interesting! Can you show us a couple of instances of each of the kinds of functions you have to process? (Put them in your question.)