# Parsing .c/.cpp/.py source files in Python to get a list of the functions contained

Tags: c++, python, c, parsing

I'm trying to learn about parsers, for Python, C and C++ source (on my own, not for a school project). Here is a summary of what i want to do: 
1) read .c/.cpp/.py source files in Python 
2) get a list of all the functions in the source files, and the span of their definitions in terms of line numbers.

So to illustrate my question, consider the following code in a file "helloWorld.cpp" (read this in python):

```
//start 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  string str = "Hello World";
  cout << str << endl; 

  return 0;
}
//end
```

What i want to get is something along: 
list of functions: 
  int main(int argc, char** argv) 
  start: line 7
  end: line 12

Any ideas on how to achieve this (some code examples would be greatly appreciated)?

Comment: See [
Is there a good Python library that can parse C++?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444961/is-there-a-good-python-library-that-can-parse-c) and [
Python - Parse a .py file, read the AST, modify it, then write back the modified source code
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/python-parse-a-py-file-read-the-ast-modify-it-then-write-back-the-modified).

Answer (score 3):

If you're really interested in learning about parsing C, you might want to look into [pycparsing](http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/). It's built on [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), so you can probably leverage what you learn from it for parsing lots of things.

Parsing C++, though, is *way* more complicated than parsing C or Python, so you may want to explore Python and C before you start digging into C++.

Comment: pycparser has moved from Google's code archive.
https://pypi.org/project/pycparser/

Answer (score 1):

Pygments might be a good place to start. It is a generic code highlighter written in python with all the languages and lots more that you were trying to parse.
You can find it here:
http://dev.pocoo.org/projects/pygments/wiki

Comment: Pygments has moved.  Its home is now https://pygments.org/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement python bindings to Clang, or, alternatively, you could just parse and analyse XML AST dumps from Clang with Python.

Answer (score 0):

For C and **especially** C++ - if you have a real-world project, I would recommend staying as close to a canonical parser implementation as possible.  C++ parsing is not for the light-hearted (and usually not done right - even by commercial compilers). I have used [gcc-xml](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) in the past just for this reason.  It uses gcc to parse the code and then translates gcc's internal representation to a referential XML representation of the code that is a little easier to grok.  It may not teach you about parsing, but it will give you some insight into the language grammar in a familiar XML data model.

For Python code you can make use of the [parser](http://docs.python.org/library/parser.html) and/or [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) modules.  I have never personally used them myself however.