# Generating tokens in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good Python library that can parse C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444961/is-there-a-good-python-library-that-can-parse-c)

I want Python to scan through a file (a .cpp file) and generate tokens from it using the in-built Python tokeniser.How can this be achieved?

Comment: Actually parser will yield tokens, so this might help you out.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444961/is-there-a-good-python-library-that-can-parse-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444961/is-there-a-good-python-library-that-can-parse-c)

Comment: @kracekumar: A parser eats tokens and generates a syntax tree. Creating the tokens is the job of a tokenizer (or "lexical analyzer").

Answer (score 0):

The built-in tokenizer and ast stuff is for parsing Python, not other languages like C++.

You may want to look at [GCC-XML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html).