# How to remove text before a particular character or string in multi-line text?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all the text before and including `*/` in a string.

For example, consider:

```
string = ''' something
other things
etc. */ extra text. 
'''
```

Here I want `extra text.` as the output.

I tried:

```
string = re.sub("^(.*)(?=*/)", "", string)
```

I also tried:

```
string = re.sub(re.compile(r"^.\*/", re.DOTALL), "", string)
```

But when I print `string`, it did not perform the operation I wanted and the whole string is printing.

Comment: does this need to be done with regex?

Comment: @depperm not necessarily. But I am using regex to remove lines in between two chars, lines start with a particular char or string. So I thought I can accomplish the question above with regex.

Comment: the problem is that `.` ignores newlines. try this pattern: `(\n|.)+\*/`. Also what happened to the space before `"extra text"`?

Comment: @pault worked perfectly.

Comment: @NewCoder and if you have multiple `*/` occurrences in text?

Comment: I have a feeling that you're trying to parse C++ code with python. [Are you writing your own compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444961/is-there-a-good-python-library-that-can-parse-c).

Comment: `string = re.sub(re.compile(r"^.*\*/", re.DOTALL), "", string)` works

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your first regex is that `.` does not match newlines as you noticed. With your second one, you were closer but forgot the `*` that time. This would work:

```
string = re.sub(re.compile(r"^.*\*/", re.DOTALL), "", string)
```

You can also just get the part of the string that comes after your "*/":

```
string = re.search(r"(\*/)(.*)", string, re.DOTALL).group(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're fine without regular expressions:

```
string[string.index("*/ ")+3:]
```

And if you want to strip that newline:

```
string[string.index("*/ ")+3:].rstrip()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: After doing some research, I found that the pattern `(\n|.)` to match everything including newlines [is inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33312193/5858851). I've updated the answer to use `[\s\S]` instead as shown on the answer I linked.

---

The problem is that `.` in python regex matches everything *except* newlines. For a regex solution, you can do the following:

```
import re

strng = ''' something
other things
etc. */ extra text. 
'''

print(re.sub("[\s\S]+\*/", "", strng))
# extra text.
```

Add in a `.strip()` if you want to remove that remaining leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

to keep text until that symbol you can do:

```
split_str = string.split(' ')
boundary = split_str.index('*/')
new = ' '.join(split_str[0:boundary])
print(new)
```

which gives you:

```
 something
other things
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string_list = string.split('*/')[1:]
string = '*/'.join(string_list)
print(string)
```

gives output as

```
' extra text. \n'
```